# How to solve "ORA-6413: Connection not open." on windows 7

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, oracle-xe

I have an ASP .NET MVC 4 application whose database (Oracle 10g) is on a remote server.

Now I want it to work with a local database server (on the same machine). I set up **Oracle 10G Express Edition**. The setup was successful and I can access the database using **SQL plus**. But my application simply doesn't connect to it (Using **Oracle.DataAccess.dll**).

I searched a lot on the internet and found out that it could be because there is a special character in the directory's path where Visual Studio 2010 is installed (Program Files (x86)). So I uninstalled it and installed it in another path with no special characters.

Still the application just won't connect to the local oracle server.

Just to test, I created another simple Console Application and wrote the code to connect to the local database in the Main() function and it successfully connected. The exact same code in the application doesn't work.

The error that I get is:

```
ORA-6413: Connection not open.
Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException was unhandled by user code
Message=ORA-6413: Connection not open.
Source=Oracle Data Provider for .NET
DataSource=""
Number=6413
Procedure=""
StackTrace:
   at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException.HandleErrorHelper(Int32 errCode, OracleConnection conn, IntPtr opsErrCtx, OpoSqlValCtx* pOpoSqlValCtx, Object src, String procedure)
   at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException.HandleError(Int32 errCode, OracleConnection conn, IntPtr opsErrCtx, Object src)
   at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleConnection.Open()
   at IBeam.Common.Repositories.SessionProvider.GetSessionFactory(String groupCode, String companyCode) in D:\Projects\IBeamNewRepo\IBeamCopy\Src\Trunk\IBeam.Common\Repositories\SessionProvider.cs:line 61
   at IBeam.Common.Repositories.SessionProvider.GetSession() in D:\Projects\IBeamNewRepo\IBeamCopy\Src\Trunk\IBeam.Common\Repositories\SessionProvider.cs:line 191
   at IBeam.Controllers.AccountController.Login(String url) in D:\Projects\IBeamNewRepo\IBeamCopy\Src\Trunk\IBeam\Controllers\AccountController.cs:line 38
   at lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] )
   at System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase controller, Object[] parameters)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.InvokeSynchronousActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass42.<BeginInvokeSynchronousActionMethod>b__41()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.<>c__DisplayClass8`1.<BeginSynchronous>b__7(IAsyncResult _)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End[TResult](IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass37.<>c__DisplayClass39.<BeginInvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__33()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass4f.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronously>b__49()
```

My Code to connect to Oracle:

```
var connection = new OracleConnection();
                    var str =
                        @"Data Source = (DESCRIPTION =
                         (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = mridula-PC)(PORT = 1521))
                         (CONNECT_DATA =
                         (SERVICE_NAME = XE)
                         )
                         );
                         User Id=app$security;
                         Password=appsecurity;";
connection.ConnectionString = str;
connection.Open(); <- Exception Here
```

My OS is `Windows 7`.

Answer (score 3):

The Best possible solution is to upgrade to Oracle 11G Release 1 version of Client tools (Build: 11.1.0.6.0) rather than applying the series of patches over the 10G client which may not produce desired results. The 11G version of the Client tools are tested and confirmed to include a FIX for the above error. If it is absolutely necessary to stick to the 10G version of the client (it shouldn't be), refer to the following:

For 32-BIT Oracle Client:

1. Install 10.2.0.2 upgrade - You need to select the correct Oracle Home path of previous 10.2.0.1 install.
2. After that you need to install a patch (5383042) for 10.2.0.2 client tools.

For 64-BIT Oracle Client:

1. Install 64bit 10.2.02 upgrade - Select the correct Oracle Home.
2. Install 64bit 10.2.03 upgrade - Select the correct Oracle Home.

Reference: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/debarchan/archive/2009/02/04/good-old-connectivity-issue.aspx

Comment: But this is about the client. What about the 10G express server? Do I need to upgrade that too?